# How to give read-only access to members in bluemix track&plan?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, devops-services

Is it possible to add members in bluemix track&plan with read-only access?
I want to limit the number of people who can add/modify work items into my project.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you want a more fine-grained access control for project members.

1. Can you not allow project members to edit work items? A short answer is no.

Check official website: https://hub.jazz.net/docs/projectadmin/

Project members have the fewest privileges and responsibilities. They can do these tasks:
    - Add and edit work items
    - Create Git branches for Git projects
    - Create tags for Git projects
    - Push and pull source code from the repository
    - View and edit pipelines
    - Add, edit, delete, and run pipeline stages or jobs

2. I think project members should have the access right to edit work items.

Bluemix track&plan is based on RTC(Rational Team Concert). I've been using RTC for team's project development for several years. It can be disturbing when someone removes a tag used in a query or changes work item to an incorrect status.

But the essence of track&plan is for team collaboration. Work item is critical to provide transparency and real-time status. Everybody on the team should have the right to add comments to the work item. My best practice is to use daily scrum meeting to review team dashboard and validate the work item status.

In real life, I seldom see team members deliberately update work items that don't belong to them. Instead, scrum master needs to motivate team to provide more update to the work items.

If you want to share the status to a stakeholder who's not in the project team, one doable option is to set your project as "public".
Try to access the link I created: https://hub.jazz.net/ccm51/quickplanner/jazzhub.html#items:projectId=_9b859SQ7EeesKZSRjqyxIQ&serverId=hub.jazz.net&planType=allwork&allIterations=true

Steps to set up your project as public:
1. Navigate to the Track&Plan dashboard. Click "Settings" icon
2. De-select "private" project checkbox & save

Comment: Thanks, very clear.
In fact, I wanted to add people who are not part of the development team but would like to view the work planning, progress etc...
But I will just use reporting instead, sending them regular 'snap shots' of illustrating the team's progress.

Comment: One doable option is to set your project as public. I just updated my original answer for your reference.